# strange issue with fonts in ionic app

Tags: fonts, ionic-framework, webfonts, google-font-api

I created an ionic application with ionic side menu template.

i am facing a strange issue with fonts. i used roboto font by linking to google fonts.

Issues i am facing are

PROFILE is sometimes shown as PRO LE .(some letters go missing)
PROFILE is sometimes shown as OQNEHKD (one ascii down).

This issues are coming before compiling the app, this will get fixed when i refresh or resize the browser.

Is this issue related to ionic ? how to resolve this issue ?

please help.

thanks in advance..

Comment: Does this only happen with this specific font? Do you have any code examples, maybe create a fiddle showing the problem?

Comment: Can you please also post a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem?